# How to read Exif information from QExifImageHeader?

Tags: qt, exif

i want to read some exif informations with QExifImageHeader (from the QT Extended Library)
(see [here](http://qt.gitorious.org/~seanharmer/qt-labs/seanharmers-scenegraph/blobs/9dead5efc0717a19eb56314c7f14479bcfadde4f/examples/photos/qexifimageheader.h))

Can someone say me how to get the informations from one tag?

I have this code:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QExifImageHeader header;
    header.loadFromJpeg("test.jpg");
    QExifValue value=header.value(QExifImageHeader::ImageWidth );
    qDebug()<<value.toByte();
   return a.exec();
```

}

The result of the qDebug() is "0".  But why?

I saw some other librarys (like exiv2). But they are to heavy for my project.

Greetings

Comment: How about checking the return value of `loadFromJpeg()`? Are you sure `value` should be something else than 0?